# AS3: fullscreen mode issue

Tags: actionscript-3, fullscreen, addeventlistener

this is my code

```
function btnClick (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL)
    {
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; 
        bcgr.visible = true;
        function imgZoom (e:MouseEvent):void
        {
            //zooming - code not relevant to my issue
        }
        stage.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, imgZoom);
    }
    else
    {
        //option1:  stage.removeEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, imgZoom);
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
        bcgr.visible = false;
        //option2:  stage.removeEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, imgZoom);
    }
}
mybtn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
```

I have two problems in this code that I can't solve.

First of all when I enter the `FULL_SCREEN - mode` the `bcg.visible` becomes `true` and when i exit  `FULL_SCREEN - mode` by clicking on `mybtn` the `bcg.visible` becomes `false`, but when i exit by hitting `escape` it doesn't. How to make it work?

And second of all I want't to remove the `eventlistener imgZoom` when I exit the `FULL_SCREEN - mode`. But when I place the `removeLEventlistener` as `option1` then turning back to  `NORMAL - mode` doesn't work, and when I place the `removeLEventlistener` as `option2` then the `listener` will not remove?

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be notified of fullscreen enter/exit events by adding a listener to the Stage: `stage.addEventListener(FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, ...)`

Here is a link to the Stage documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#event:fullScreen

For the `imgZoom` issue you need to move the definition outside the `btnClick` function. The `imgZoom` variable is local to the `btnClick` function so it gets redefined each time the function is called. This means the second time you click on the button `imgZoom` is `undefined` and you can never remove the previous event listener.

Moving the function definition outside the `btnClick` handler will let you remove it again later.

Here is everything together:

```
function imgZoom (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    //zooming - code not relevant to my issue
}

function fullScreenListener (e:FullScreenEvent)
{
    bcgr.visible = e.fullScreen;
    if (e.fullScreen)
    {
        stage.addEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, imgZoom);
    }
    else
    {
        stage.removeEventListener (MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, imgZoom);
    }
}

function btnClick (e:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (stage.displayState == StageDisplayState.NORMAL)
    {
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN; 
    }
    else
    {
        stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.NORMAL;
    }
}

stage.addEventListener (FullScreenEvent.FULL_SCREEN, fullScreenListener);
mybtn.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, btnClick);
```